# Ember.js - accessing items of a record array in a Handlebars view

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a model property called `players` which is a record array returned by an ember-data store. I would like to access one of its items in the view without the need of iterating it whole. I know that if I need the first one `Ember.Enumerable` has a `firstObject` method that I can use like this:

```
{{ players.firstObject.name }}
```

but for other indices, the thing gets tricky:

```
{{ players.[1].name }}   // does not work for Ember records
```

as the handlebars notation `players.[1].name` does not work for record array. But it works for native JS arrays. So one solution is to override the property on the controller like this:

```
players: (function() {
  return this.get('model.players').toArray();
}).property('players'),
```

Another would be to make a Handlebars helper maybe. But my question is (finally): why isn't it working by default? Is there a reason why I shouldn't be converting it into an array? Are there methods that I can mixin into the record array so that it will work as expected in handlebars?

Answer (score 0):

rarely do you need access to an item in the array that isn't the first or last, and if you do then you generally know something magical about item at index n.  If so, create a computed property to return that object.  It makes for more maintainability as well.

```
coolPlayer: function(){
  return this.get('players').objectAt(1);
}.property('players.[]')
```

Then just use `coolPlayer` in your template

```
{{coolPlayer.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should usually get the index of the item *somehow* through the route, if not by association to another model or parameter then by filtering based on parameters coming from the route. Otherwise the necessary data to select an item should come from some controller (or even less likely a view etc.).

After that your either displaying a list (with each) or a single item, both of which are computed properties, based on variables in your app.

Handlebars is meant to be logic-less.

However to select an item at a certain index use `.objectAt(index)`.  Just not in the template.